# Why does this Happen? (C programming Error)

Tags: c

I have written a program to create a 2D word search game, that allows the user to choose from a category and the program will generate the word search containing words from said category.
however when i compile the program i get an error i have never seen before and i cannot work out how to fix it.

This is the Error I get -

```
 TheRealFawcett:Wordsearch therealfawcett$ gcc -o Wordsearch1 
 Wordsearch1.c
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_main", referenced from:
      implicit entry/start for main executable
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
 invocation)
 TheRealFawcett:Wordsearch therealfawcett$
```

This Is My Code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WIDTH 16
#define HEIGHT 16
#define NWORDS 6

char wordsearch[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

/* horizontaly */

int canPlaceH (const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  if ((strlen(word) + j) > WIDTH)
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    j += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
};

void placeH(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i][j++] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
};

/* verticaly */

int canPlaceV(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  if ((strlen(word) + i) > HEIGHT)
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    i += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
};

void placeV(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i++][j] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
};

/* diagonal up */

int canPlaceDU(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  int ln = strlen(word);

  if (((ln + j) > WIDTH) || ((i - ln) < 0))
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    i -= 1;
    j += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
};

void placeDU(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i--][j++] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
};

/* diagonal down */

int canPlaceDD(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  int ln = strlen(word);

  if (((ln + j) > WIDTH) || ((i + ln) > HEIGHT))
    return 0;

  do {
    if ((wordsearch[i][j] != 0) && (wordsearch[i][j] != *word))
      return 0;
    i += 1;
    j += 1;
  } while (*++word);

  return 1;
};

void placeDD(const char * word, int i, int j)
{
  do {
    wordsearch[i++][j++] = *word;
  }  while (*++word);
};

void fillWordsearch(const char ** a, int sz)
{
  /* first step add words from a */
  const char * used[NWORDS - 1] = { NULL }; /* to not get two times 
the same word */

  for (int w = 0; w != NWORDS; ++w) {
    /* random choice of a word not yet used */
    const char * word;

    for (;;) {
      word = a[rand() % sz];
      int i;

      /* check not yet used */
      for (i = 0; i != w; ++i)
        if (!strcmp(used[i], word))
          break;

      if (i == w) {
        /* not yet used */
        used[w] = word;
        break;
      }
    };

    /* random placement */

    int i, j, d;
    typedef int (*canFunc)(const char *, int, int);
    typedef void (*placeFunc)(const char *, int, int);
    const canFunc canPlace[] = { canPlaceH, canPlaceV, canPlaceDU, 
canPlaceDD };
    const placeFunc place[] = { placeH, placeV, placeDU, placeDD };

    do {
      i = rand() % HEIGHT;
      j = rand() % WIDTH;
      d = rand() % 4;
    } while (!(*canPlace[d])(word, i, j));
    (*place[d])(word, i, j);



#ifdef DEBUG
  for (int i = 0; i != HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != WIDTH; ++j)
      putchar((wordsearch[i][j] == 0) ? '.' : wordsearch[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
  };
  putchar('\n');
#endif

  /* second step fill not yet set characters with random lowercase 
letters */
  int q,w;

  for (q = 0; q < HEIGHT; q++)
    for (w = 0; w != WIDTH; ++w)
      if (wordsearch[q][w] == 0)
        wordsearch[q][w] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1);
};

int main();

  const char *animalArray[] = {
    "lynx",
    "kitten",
    "cheetah",
    "ape",
    "doe",
    "reindeer",
    "whale",
    "baboon",
    "skunk",
    "dugong",
    "elephant",
    "anteater",
    "chameleon",
    "lizaed",
    "horse"
  };

  const char *colourArray[] = {
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue",
    "black",
    "pink",
    "yellow",
    "brown",
    "orange",
    "purple",
    "black",
    "white",
    "cyan",
    "maroon",
    "magenta",
    "grey"
  };

  const char *videogameArray[] = {
    "fortnite",
    "fifa",
    "hytale",
    "soma",
    "prey",
    "destiny",
    "titanfall",
    "woldenstein",
    "battlefield",
    "fallout",
    "tekken",
    "skyrim",
    "dishonored",
    "uncharted",
    "anthem"
  };

  const char *sportsArray[] = {
    "basketball",
    "football",
    "cricket",
    "wrestling",
    "fencing",
    "rowing",
    "volleyball",
    "baseball",
    "hockey",
    "racing",
    "golf",
    "bobsleigh",
    "curling",
    "snowboarding",
    "bowling"
  };

  const char *countryArray[] = {
    "england",
    "ireland",
    "china",
    "wales",
    "bangladesh",
    "maldives",
    "slovenia",
    "uruguay",
    "colombia",
    "samoa",
    "jamaica",
    "malta",
    "bulgaria",
    "armenia",
    "gamnbia"
  };

  printf("--------------------------------\n");
  printf("| Welcome to the WordSearch Game|\n");
  printf("--------------------------------\n");
  printf("Choose a Category - \n");
  printf("Option 1 - Animals\n");
  printf("Option 2 - Colours\n");
  printf("Option 3 - Video Games\n");
  printf("Option 4 - Sports\n");
  printf("Option 5 - Countries\n");

 int i;

  if ((scanf("%d", &i) != 1) || (i < 1) || (i > 5))
    return;

  srand(time(NULL));

   switch (i) {
  case 1:
    fillWordsearch(animalArray, 
sizeof(animalArray)/sizeof(*animalArray));
    break;
  case 2:
    fillWordsearch(colourArray, 
sizeof(colourArray)/sizeof(*colourArray));
    break;
  case 3:
    fillWordsearch(videogameArray, 
sizeof(videogameArray)/sizeof(*videogameArray));
    break;
  case 4:
    fillWordsearch(sportsArray, 
sizeof(sportsArray)/sizeof(*sportsArray));
    break;
  default:
    fillWordsearch(countryArray, 
sizeof(countryArray)/sizeof(*countryArray));
    break;
  };

    /* print result */
  for (i = 0; i != HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != WIDTH; ++j)
      putchar(wordsearch[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
  };

  return;
};
```

This is the new errors that i get, however when i change them i get new errors.

This is the least amount of errors that i get -

```
TheRealFawcett:Wordsearch therealfawcett$ gcc -o Wordsearch1 
Wordsearch1.c
Wordsearch1.c:173:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
TheRealFawcett:Wordsearch therealfawcett$
```

Comment: @ChristianGibbons i have now edited this

Comment: Does it happen with some simple "hello world" program? BTW, you should not put semicolons after function implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying you didn't provide a `main()` function. Looking at your code I see the following:

```
int main();
```

This is a function declaration not a definition. It looks like you've forgotten the curly braces around the body of your `main()` function.

I also see you keep putting a semicolon after the closing bracket of all your functions. This isn't required and makes me wonder what terrible resource you're using to learn C.

Edit:

Your `fillWordsearch()` function has unbalanced curly braces. It's missing a `}` brace somewhere.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to blame the learning resource.  It's not too difficult for a beginner to mix up when to use a semicolon with functions.

Comment: @TheRealFawcett You're also putting unnecessary semicolons after the closing bracket of your `for` loops and `switch` statement. These also aren't necessary and it doesn't give me much confidence in your lecturer's knowledge of C.

Comment: i think i have now rectified this but i still get that same error?

Comment: @TheRealFawcett You have some other errors that I've added to my answer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace this is the new error that i get after all changed but when i do what the compiler tells me i get 20+ new errors

TheRealFawcett:Wordsearch therealfawcett$ gcc -o Wordsearch1 Wordsearch1.c
Wordsearch1.c:173:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
TheRealFawcett:Wordsearch therealfawcett$

Comment: @TheRealFawcett [Here is your code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Sh3KgE). I added the missing `{` at the start of `main()` and guessed where the missing `}` belongs in `fillWordsearch()` (line 152). It compiles but still has a lot of warnings.

Comment: @Blastfurnace i have already fixed all errors now, but thank you for your time.
my issue now is that when a category is chosen the program just takes forever to do anything if it does at all ( i dont know im still waiting)

Comment: @TheRealFawcett If you can't easily find a logic error my best advice is to step through the program with a debugger. It will help you see the run-time values of variables and possibly see where the logic isn't what you intended.

Comment: @Blastfurnace i ran my code through a debugger and this is what i got - Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0s 9432KB
what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
int main();

  const char *animalArray[] = {
```

you should have:

```
int main()
{
  const char *animalArray[] = {
```

Comment: @TheRealFawcett but your question is not about those errors.  Start a new question now you've fixed that one.

Comment: @TheRealFawcett you should not do that. That is a different question. SO is not a discussion forum. This and other answers given are acceptable answers to your original question, but you cannot expect those that have helped you to maintain their answers to your moving target. Besides you clearly now have a simple issue of balanced braces, which you can surely figure out for yourself - that's just counting!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a `main` function. I see the line

`int main();`

but it is not implemented anywhere. The error you are getting is because the compiler doesn't know where to start the program. Perhaps this is a typo.

Perhaps you mean't to close the `fillWordsearch` function and start the `main()` function.

```
}

int main()
{
```